# Arbitrary number of tests with GNU Autotest

Tags: autotools, m4

I'm working on a project using Autotools and want to integrate Autotest for all
the functional tests. Each test has to be run like this:

```sh
./program <test file>
```

My `$(top_srcdir)/tests` directory looks like this:

```sh
% ls -1p
    good/ # Directory containing files expected to pass.
    bad/  # Directory containing files expected to fail.
    testsuite.at # The test suite.
    # Makefile.am, atlocal.in, etc...
```

Both `good/` and `bad/` contains an average of 150 test files.
I would like to avoid typing each test by hand, and I can't seem to find how to
reproduce something like what's next with m4/Autotest macros:

```sh
for i in $(ls good/) ; do
    AT_SETUP([$i])
    AT_CHECK([./program $i])
    AT_CLEANUP
done
```

The real-world case which is the closest to mine (and that I found) lies in the
test suite of the m4 project which generates a `generated.at` file using its
own documentation.
Should I follow this way and generate `good.at` and `bad.at` before invoking `autom4te` on `testsuite.at`, or is there a way using m4/Autotest macros ?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, just add `echo` statements to your snippet and redirect output to `good.at`.  Make sure that `good.at` will be distributed so not to impose a dependency on your users.